# Converting Bytes To string

Tags: c#, hash, c#-to-vb.net

I've trying hash512 as value,

I have some example code written in c sharp but i wanted to do it in vb.net

I'm struggling with the last part ByteToString, i don't know what current or t is?

Can someone please help me convert this to vb?

Thanks

```
 private static string Gethmacsha512(Encoding encode, string key, string url)
    {
        // doing the encoding
        var keyByte = encode.GetBytes(key);
        string result;



        var hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(keyByte);
         hmacsha512.ComputeHash(encode.GetBytes(url));


         result = ByteToString(hmacsha512.Hash);


        return result;
    }
    static string ByteToString(IEnumerable<byte> buff)

    {



        return buff.Aggregate("", (current, t) => current + t.ToString("X2"));

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and why is it not working?

Comment: It's called a lambda expression.  in VB the syntax would be `Function(current, t) current & t.ToString("X2")`

Comment: Thank you for that, is the  => significant in VB as i'm now getting a different result between the two

Comment: You can also try to convert this: `BitConverter.ToString(buff).Replace("-", "")`

Comment: No.  In any context I can think of, `=>` is invalid syntax in VB.  The closest thing is the `>=` comparison operator (i.e. is greater or equal).  In fact, if you type `=>` in a VB file in visual studio, it will often auto-correct it to `>=`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I disagree.  What it is doing (encoding the bytes as a string of 2-digit hex numbers per byte) is just as safe as base 64.  Base 64 would be shorter, and just as standard, but if the code needs it to be hex, there's really no reason to avoid it.

Comment: @AshleyMorgan If you're not getting the intended results after converting it to VB, and you need help, you are going to need to be more specific.  Edit your question to show the full converted-to-VB code as well as an example of some input along with what output you get from both methods (C# and VB) so we can see how they are different.

Comment: @StevenDoggart That's what I get for not seeing the "X2" :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this please :

```
static string ByteToString(System.Text.Encoding encode, IEnumerable<byte> buff)
{
    return encode.GetString(buff.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the help the reason it didn't work was because I was using the wrong key to hash, bitConverter.ToString(buff).Replace("-","") was what I used in the end